# How can I get Firebug to start automatically in a popup window?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I've got Firebug open on my website, and then I click a button which opens a popup window. However, Firebug is always greyed out by default in the popup window. I can click the icon or press F12 to start it, but I really need it to start itself, immediately, because I want to watch the AJAX requests that happen on page initialization of the popup window. By the time I click or press F12 it's already too late; it's missed those requests.

How do I get Firebug to persist in my popup window?

Comment: F5? depending on your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in the [Firebug menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Start_Button) called *On For All Web Pages*, which opens Firebug automatically. Though unfortunately that also doesn't allow you to track the network requests.

So this actually looks like a bug to me. You should [report that in the Firebug issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), so it can be fixed.

Comment: This worked right away for me, so I'm not sure what bug you've noticed. Thanks for pointing out this option to me!

Comment: Good that it worked for you. For me the *Net* panel stayed empty directly after the popup window opened.